# How to change Apache Karaf / Jetty / Pax-Web default path from / to your-custom-path/?

Tags: java, jetty, apache-karaf, pax-web

I have a Karaf installation with some .war-files in it. 
Each of them is available via hostname:port/individual-context-path.

How can i redirect the hostname:port/ call, which gives a 404 actually - to a given context-path?

Which files defines the jetty / karaf "root-path"?

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I dont where i can define the default route/path/connection? for my karaf instance. It should point to a given war-context-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't re-direct or route a certain path to another, but you can register your application to be registered at Web-ContextPath "/". 
oth all servlets registered with any HttpService/WecContainer or registerd as Servlet Service (OSGi) will be registered with the "/" context path, all extras are aliases on those.

Comment: Thank you! Ah, you are the guy from the Apache Karaf Cookbook - which i have now on my table. Thanks for that good book as well.

Comment: You're welcome and I hope that book does help you get around the specialties :-)